# Kendo UI open view in current tab

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I currently have a Kendoui template with two tab items. How can I open new views in these tabs?

I want to be able to do something like:

Tab 1 -> View 1 -> View 2

Where if view2 is open, it remains open in Tab 1.

Basically, View 1 contains a listview. I want to be able to select an item in the listview and open a new view to show more details about the item. This view should have a back button that takes you back to the listview.

Having a hard time figuring out how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview#change)** event of the ListView and the **[activateTab](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#activatetab)** method of the tabStrip object.